# CodeIgniter query from sql

Tags: sql, codeigniter

How can I transform this sql to codeigniter query? I have screenshot of an EER diagram to help you understand better. So there are three tables to join. I guess, one is "pjesma", then "izvodjac", and "izvodi_pjesmu". This sql works when I run it and gives me results I want. I am also using pagination so I need limit and offset somehow included.

[image: EER diagram]

```
SELECT pjesma_id, naslov, naziv
FROM pjesma p, izvodjac i, izvodi_pjesmu ip
WHERE p.pjesma_id = ip.pjesma_pjesma_id
AND i.izvodjac_id = ip.izvodjac_izvodjac_id
```

in model:

```
public function paginacija_pjesme($limit, $offset) {

    $this->db->select('pjesma_id', 'naslov', 'naziv');
    $this->db->from('pjesma p');
    $this->db->join('izvodi_pjesmu ip', 'p.pjesma_id=ip.pjesma_pjesma_id');
    $this->db->join('izvodjac i', 'i.izvodjac_id=ip.izvodjac_izvodjac_id');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

EDIT: 
So in select I used wrong syntax, this line:

```
$this->db->select('pjesma_id', 'naslov', 'naziv');
```

should be like this:

```
$this->db->select('pjesma_id, naslov, naziv');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things, as you are dealing with objects within the query builder class, you can method-chain and make things a little less cluttered.

You are maybe getting an ambiguous column error, joining and not prefixing your select. Hard to tell without the error being posted you are facing.

Always best to (just in case) set defaults to your method arguments as well, in case you pass a blank variable (or don't need to for whatever reason).

When you are using multiple tables in the FROM statement you are actually doing a CROSS JOIN, and your new code is giving INNER JOIN,trying the join syntax direct to your SQL server might help as you are not actually doing the same thing between your first written query, and the codeigniter one..
Try the below with LEFT join just to see... If there are NULL joins using INNER they will be omitted

```
public function paginacija_pjesme($limit = 10, $offset = 0) {

    $query = $this->db->select('p.pjesma_id, p.naslov, i.naziv')
        ->from('pjesma p')
        ->join('izvodi_pjesmu ip', 'p.pjesma_id = ip.pjesma_pjesma_id', 'left')
        ->join('izvodjac i', 'i.izvodjac_id = ip.izvodjac_izvodjac_id', 'left')
        ->limit($limit, $offset)
        ->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

Are you getting any errors? what do you see if you `print_r($query->result())` ?

try also spitting out `$this->db->last_query()` - this will output the SQL codeigniter has build. Then running this directly to your database, and see the results from there. You might even see the issue without needing to run it.

This is an example of what your current codeigniter code is generating (as you can see, different to your original query):

```
SELECT pjesma_id, naslov, naziv
FROM pjesma p
INNER JOIN izvodi_pjesmu ip ON p.pjesma_id = ip.pjesma_pjesma_id
INNER JOIN izvodjac i ON i.izvodjac_id = ip.izvodjac_izvodjac_id
# LIMIT 10,0
```

Comment: I killed my answer as it was indeed incorrect as you noted. Yours has a lot more detail covering all the other possibilities.

Comment: Being explicit doesn't hurt at all, omitting it in that case isn't an issue :)

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [pjesma_id] => 11 ) )   -this is print_r result, Thank you very much

Comment: SELECT `p`.`pjesma_id` FROM `pjesma` `p` LEFT JOIN `izvodi_pjesmu` `ip` ON `p`.`pjesma_id`=`ip`.`pjesma_pjesma_id` LEFT JOIN `izvodjac` `i` ON `i`.`izvodjac_id`=`ip`.`izvodjac_izvodjac_id` LIMIT 5  -this is output from last_query()

Comment: when i run this query you wrote (with INNER JOIN) in workbench it works as i want

Comment: Then the issue is with how you're processing the result

Comment: in view i try to display "naslov" and "naziv" and i get undefined property error, thank you again for your help, query needs to be modified i guess let me try

Comment: How are you handling it after the method returns the result object?

Comment: $data['pjesme'] = $this->pjesma_model->paginacija_pjesme($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(2)); ---this is passed to the view, and in the view foreach loop $pjesme as $pjesma, $pjesma->naslov, $pjesma->naziv...And when i run query in workbench it gives only "pjesma_id" indeed

Comment: ok, somehow my SELECT does not include naslov and naziv only pjesma_id, but i put it just like you suggested, we have to avoid long commenting i cant go to chat, i'm new here

Comment: very sorry the syntax was wrong as I copied your original code and didn't pay enough attention please see my updated example for the CI code (model). also with your loop:  ` foreach ($pjesme as $row) ...then... $row->naslov,  ... etc` using the same variable name will not work correctly

Comment: $query = $this->db->select('p.pjesma_id', 'i.naslov', 'naziv') should be $query = $this->db->select('p.pjesma_id, p.naslov, i.naziv'), we have error in select from codeigniter point of view, it works like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135446/discussion-between-brian-ramsey-and-zoran-koprek).